# jQuery fade to different background images for body set by interval set by a specific folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to fade the body background to other images in a specific folder set by an interval. I have got the script to run the setInterval but it does not change the background-image at all, infact it does not change it even to a blank image. The images are located in the folder with the script.js file (same file where the script below is called from). I am running a simple randomiser to determine which file to run (files are named 1,2,3,4.jpg etc).

It would be ideal if i could preload the images, but that I guess is another issue:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

var image;

function changeImage() {
    image = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
    $("body").css("background-image",image+".jpg");
}

setInterval(changeImage, 3000);
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can extend the jQuery to:

```
$.fn.preload = function() {
    this.each(function(){
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
    });
}
```

now you can preload the images by :

```
$(['1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg','4.jpg']).preload();
```

and your code to change the background may look like

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var image;

    function changeImage() {
        image = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
        $("body").css("background-image","url('" + image+ ".jpg')");
     }
   });

setInterval(changeImage, 3000);
```

Comment: ^this, and you cannot fade background images. You would have to put that in a div, position it fixed and put it in the background. you can set the other elements to position:relative to set the proper z-indexes

Comment: i have not tried to fade background. for the OP code i thought by fading he means to change it after every 3000ms so i did that ;)

Comment: Oh, like that. I assumed "I want to fade the body background to" actually ment fading ;-)
n1 Champ.

Comment: may be you can pointout this to OP. that what actually fading means ;)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are setting the property for background-image, but not specifying url, try this:

```
$("body").css("background-image","url(" + image+ ".jpg)");
```

or an alternative would be

```
image = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
image = "url(" + image + ".jpg)"
$("body").css("background-image",image);
```

Answer (score 0):

You use this jQuery without double cot in url and use background insted of background-image

```
image = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
$("body").css({background:"url(" + image  + ".jpg)"})
```